# dropping columns based on another dataframe & adding a panda series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let s assume we have 3 dataframes.

- df1 has 14 columns
- df2 has 26 columns (which was created from a merge of df1 with another dataframe)
- df3 that has 15 columns

What I want is to drop the columns of df2. I want to keep the common columns that they have with df1 and then append 1 extra column from df3(that I will specify by name)
I tried something like the following

```
df2 = df2[(df1.column) & df3['Name'])
```

but it did not work
I also tried

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df3['Name'])
```

but again it did not work (it returned an empty dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Use an index [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
new_df2 = df2[list(df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns))+['Name']]
```